# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate factory class: org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, rpc

I am new to spring and as a starting point followed the tutorial @ [Spring IO Tutorials](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/)

I've downloaded project from spring initializer using `Web`, `JPA`, `H2`, `Lombok` and using **Eclipse** with **Maven**.

Following are the code set:

> PayrollApplication.java

```
  package com.spring.payroll;

  import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
  import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

  @SpringBootApplication     

  public class PayrollApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PayrollApplication.class, args);
  }

   }
```

> Employee.java

```
  package com.spring.payroll;

  import lombok.Data;
  import javax.persistence.Entity;
  import javax.persistence.Id;
  import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;;

  @Data     
  @Entity   

  // This is a domain object definition

  public class Employee {

      private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
      private String name;
      private String role;

      //Constructor now

      Employee(String name, String role){
                this.name = name;
                this.role = role;
      }
        }
```

> EmployeeRepository Interface:

```
 package com.spring.payroll;

 import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

 public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{

 }
```

**LoadDatabase** to put some initial data:

```
 package com.spring.payroll;

 import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
 import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

 @Configuration
 @Slf4j

 public class LoadDatabase {

     @Bean
     CommandLineRunner initDatabase(EmployeeRepository repository) {

    return args -> {
        repository.save(new Employee("A La BD", "Engineer"));
        repository.save(new Employee("Arvind", "Engineer"));
        System.out.println("Preloading data successful");
         };
       }    
    }
```

When I attempt maven clean install, it fails at the TEST step with below:

<< Edited after retrying by adding Jackson dependencies to pom.xml>>

```
10:15:06.587 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate factory class: org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:163)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.loadPostProcessors(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:160)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference
    at org.springframework.boot.json.JsonParserFactory.getJsonParser(JsonParserFactory.java:41)
    at org.springframework.boot.cloud.CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.<init>(CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:104)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
10:15:06.589 [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@757277dc] to prepare test instance [com.spring.payroll.PayrollApplicationTests@2c35e847]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate factory class: org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:163)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.loadPostProcessors(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:160)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference
    at org.springframework.boot.json.JsonParserFactory.getJsonParser(JsonParserFactory.java:41)
    at org.springframework.boot.cloud.CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.<init>(CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:104)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

My pom.xml: <>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>payroll</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>payroll</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                  <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If I run the application, it gives following error:

```
10:24:31.447 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/logback-core-1.2.3.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/snakeyaml-1.19.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/spring-boot-starter-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/spring-expression-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/spring-jcl-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/C:/NotBackedUp/eclipse/eclipse-workspace/payroll/payroll/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.2/aspectjweaver-1.9.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/3.2.0/HikariCP-3.2.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.3/javax.transaction-api-1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/javax/activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.3.7.Final/hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.2.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/javax/persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2/javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.23.1-GA/javassist-3.23.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.9.7/byte-buddy-1.9.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.5.Final/jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.4.0/classmate-1.4.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/dom4j/dom4j/2.1.1/dom4j-2.1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.4.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.4.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/2.1.4.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.1.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-aspects-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.11.1/log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.11.1/log4j-api-2.11.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.25/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.23/snakeyaml-1.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.9.8/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.8.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.8/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.8.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.9.8/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.8.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.14/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/9.0.14/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.14.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.14/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.14.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.14.Final/hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-expression-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.197/h2-1.4.197.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.4/lombok-1.18.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.5.2/jackson-core-2.5.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.5.2/jackson-annotations-2.5.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/sheelava/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.5.2/jackson-databind-2.5.2.jar]
10:24:31.833 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/support/StandardServletEnvironment
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getOrCreateEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:460)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:356)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at com.spring.payroll.PayrollApplication.main(PayrollApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

I had a similar but different code which is also failing with similar error. I am missing something - please share if you had faced a similar issue. Thank you.

Comment: I did not add any Jackson dependencies, it's already part of Spring-starter-web, For reference: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa

Comment: From my m2 repo, I can track till .m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core but not further to com\fasterxml\jackson\core\type\TypeReference. Error also points to same: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Gopi, @dkb. After few iterations I was able to solve the issue and make my application run fine. 
Basically I had spring jars in both jdk/jre/lib and inside my .m2/repository (guessing some earlier work) & both were in my classpath. Upon deleting the old jars, application worked perfectly fine.

Two more learnings :

1) Jackson databind will implicitly include core and annotations. Hence if we have difference in versions, it will also cause issues. Either we add exclusions or do not specify core & annotations if we specify databind.

2) Jackson: There is a new class InvalidDefinitionException in 2.9.4 version only which caused me some issues.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace it seems Jackson-core jar issue.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference
```

Add the following dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
<version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried this but again it is failing.    <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.2</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Just to test, I changed the version to 2.1.2 for Jackson to be in synch with spring-boot version. Still no luck and same error. My applications.properties is blank - has this anything to do ?

Comment: Thanks @Gopi, dkb. After few iterations I was able to solve the issue and make my application run fine. Basically I had spring jars in both jdk/jre/lib and inside my .m2/repository (guessing I had it during my earlier work). Upon deleting the old jars, application worked perfectly fine.