# Springboot application is not working in Intellij but works in other IDEs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

My spring boot application is working fine in IDEs like Netbeans and Eclipse but doesn't work in Intellij.

Intellij is throwing this error while starting the application. I tried to clean the cache and restarted the Intellij but didn't help. Can someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

```
2021-12-29 19:05:22,824[main] ERROR [o.s.b.SpringApplication]  Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate factory class [org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor] for factory type [org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:168)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.loadPostProcessors(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:205)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:196)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:188)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:206)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.fmr.amt.AmtCdsHoldingsEventsHandlerApplication.main(AmtCdsHoldingsEventsHandlerApplication.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(ReflectionUtils.java:185)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:164)
    ... 27 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Check if this post help you. [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate factory class: org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54642801/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-unable-to-instantiate-factory-class-org-spr)

Comment: Looks like different (not compatible) versions of the Spring libraries are used. Verify you have correct spring libraries versions set in pom.xml. Try fresh re-import project from Maven pom.xml in IDE: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple JDK installed on your system? Please check the project settings in idea, select the right jdk version(SDKs in platform settings) you project use.